# how to get the character before the ( and also after the ( symbol

Tags: c#

kindly refer this photo for the details, feel free to ask more info from 
[image]

I want to get the character before the ( and also ( symbol, anyone got idea how to do it?

Comment: Well a regular expression would probably work, or you could use IndexOf and Substring if you really wanted to. Have you tried anything yet? What happened?

Comment: so what did you try? we dont just write code for you

Comment: Do you intend to get all characters from the string? `A(` and `B(` and `C(` ? or just the first?

Comment: @BugFinder " we dont just write code for you" apparently we do ;)

Comment: @user7755725 : before and after that symbol ( ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `RegEx`

```
string input = "Person A(Owner), Person B(Group Manager)";
string[] result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, @"\w\(")
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(x => x.Value)
                        .ToArray();
// ["A(", "B(" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

if the length of the text is always the same

then try this out..

```
//store your words into input
string input = textbox1.text ;

string something = input.Substring(input.Length);

// collects letters from individual positions
string filtered = something[7]+something[8]+something[9]+something[10]+something[11]+something[12]+something[13];

label1.text = filtered.tostring(); // display the filtered stuff
```

this is 1 method to do it.

Comment: probably A, B and C are names that can vary and the length will not be known in advance

Comment: i was planning to use substring but my manager told me not to used it because the QE may change the value of it

Comment: That won't work. How do you want to add characters up and store it in one char variable?

Comment: Also "something" would be empty or an error will be thrown. The first parameter in String.Substring gives the start index. In this case you start from index 10 in a 10 char long string.

Comment: @DanielFrühauf yup i know. thats y i said "if the length of the text is always the same". Nevertheless thanks for your feedbacks.

Comment: "input.Substring(input.Length)" will not give you anything but an empty string